# typescript tsc is not excluding @types/corejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

Tsconfig:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"noEmitHelpers": true,
"lib": [
  "es6",
  "dom"
],
"types": [
  "hammerjs",
  "jasmine",
  "node",
  "selenium-webdriver",
  "webpack",
  "core-js",
  "google-maps"
]
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules"
"e2e"
],
"include": [
"src/**/*"
],
"filesGlob": [
"./src/**/*.ts",
"./test/**/*.ts",
"!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
"./src/custom-typings.d.ts"
],

}
```

When executing tsc I get following errors:

> node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(262,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'flags' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(276,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(311,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(318,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(457,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Symbol"', but here has type 'string'.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(457,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(464,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(492,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'hasInstance' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(498,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'isConcatSpreadable' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(504,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'iterator' must have identical modifiers.
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(510,5): error TS2687: All declarations of

Why node_modules are not ignored when executing tsc command.
I am using typescript in 2.0.3 version

Answer (score 4):

Your `tsconfig.json` file lists `core-js` in the `"types"` property. This instructs the compiler to include `node_module\@types\core-js`. if you do not need it remove that entry.

See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types for more details about `@types`, and `types` in `tsconfig.json`.